# Javascript Filter with one or more than field

Tags: javascript, filter

I am working on JavaScript filter.I have to filter data with one column or more than one column with following requirement and please see below example of object.

```js
var arr = [
      {
       "t_id" : "abc",
       "s_id" : "pai"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "pai",
       "s_id" : "par"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "pai",
       "s_id" : "pas"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "pai",
       "s_id" : "pai"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "par",
       "s_id" : "pas"
      }      
]
```

When I will apply filter for with field t_id with 'pai' value so it will return below object.

```js
{
           "t_id" : "pai",
           "s_id" : "par"
          },
          {
           "t_id" : "pai",
           "s_id" : "pas"
          },
          {
           "t_id" : "pai",
           "s_id" : "pai"
          }
```

And when I will apply filter using field s_id with 'pai' value it should return below object.

```js
         {
           "t_id" : "abc",
           "s_id" : "pai"
          },
          {
           "t_id" : "pai",
           "s_id" : "par"
          },
          {
           "t_id" : "pai",
           "s_id" : "pas"
          },
          {
           "t_id" : "pai",
           "s_id" : "pai"
          }
```

Basically when I will apply filter for field 's_id'. It will consider filter for 't_id' too. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. We can start from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter to return `true` either of the conditional matches:

```js
var arr = [{"t_id":"abc","s_id":"pai"},{"t_id":"pai","s_id":"par"},{"t_id":"pai","s_id":"pas"},{"t_id":"pai","s_id":"pai"},{"t_id":"par","s_id":"pas"}];
console.log(arr.filter(item => item.t_id === 'pai' || item.s_id === 'pai'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by passing around object name and value.

```js
var arr = [
      {
       "t_id" : "abc",
       "s_id" : "pai"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "pai",
       "s_id" : "par"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "pai",
       "s_id" : "pas"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "pai",
       "s_id" : "pai"
      },
      {
       "t_id" : "par",
       "s_id" : "pas"
      }      
]

function myFilter(name, value) {
    var filteredArr = arr.filter(obj => obj[name] === value);
  
    return filteredArr;
}

var filterTID = myFilter("t_id", "pai");
var filterSID = myFilter("s_id", "pai");

console.log(filterTID);
console.log(filterSID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array for the keys to check and check if the property is equal to the wanted value, while filtering the array.

```js
var array = [{ t_id: "abc", s_id: "pai" }, { t_id: "pai", s_id: "par" }, { t_id: "pai", s_id: "pas" }, { t_id: "pai", s_id: "pai" }, { t_id: "par", s_id: "pas" }],
    keys = ['t_id', 's_id'],
    value = 'pai',
    result = array.filter(o => keys.some(k => o[k] === value));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```